# iOS: crashlytics integration without cocoapods and plugin

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, crashlytics

Is there any way that I can integrate crashlytics into my swift ios project without using their plugin and without using cocoapods?

Comment: Mike from Fabric and Crashlytics here. Currently, those are the only two officially supported ways of adding an app. What would your preference be?

Comment: My preference would be a universal framework. I don't currently use CocoaPods and I don't really want to have to adopt it just to integrate Crashlytics.

Comment: @GregBrown there appears to be a way to do this now: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/manual-install

Answer (score 4):

It now appears possible to install Crashlytics without Cocoapods: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/manual-install